# Why is a static IP address required to use financial FIX protocol connectivity?

Tags: validation, ip, fix-protocol, static-ip-address, user-identification

Why do vendors who provide FIX protocol connectivity require a static IP address? Is the only reason user identification/validation? Or is there any other reason behind that?

Thanks

Comment: Any reason for the 'close' vote? Am happy to revise the question if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the reason is that the (free registration required, sadly) [FIXT specification](http://fixprotocol.org/documents/3070/FIX_Transport_1.1.pdf) test cases (specifically test case 1S/c) requires IP validation for Logon messages. It does not exclude the possibility of allowing an entire IP block (just references "system configuration" as a source of the allowed IP), but most vendors follow the spirit of highest possible security.

The spec (page 39) further mentions unauthorized attempts to break into your system as the reason for doing the validation.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. How do most banks then handle multiple FIX connections to the same counter party given some teams require several FIX connections? They are running several static IPs? I have heard of couple teams who run multiple FIX connections to the same counter party, however each connection most likely had a different authenticated machine/user behind it which makes me guess they must have several static IPs.

Comment: @MattWolf I can't speak for "most banks" but when I've had to set up a connection, the bank required a signed terms of use and a list of static IPs that were to be allowed. Sounds straight forward enough to be common practice without compromising security.